# Migration from ASP.NET web service with SOAP Header and Mtom, WSE-3 to WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services

I need to do migration from ASP.NET web service to WCF. Current code is like this:

Server Side:

```
    public class MyType
    {
    public int x;
    public string s;
    }

    public class MyService : WebService
    {
    public MyType myObj;

    [WebMethod]
    [SoapHeader("myObj", Direction=SoapHeaderDirection.InOut)]
    public string SomeMethod() // NO Parameter!!!
    {
            if (myObj.x > 5)
               return myObj.s;
            else
               return "Less than 5";    
        }
    }
</code>
```

Client Side:

```
    MyService service = new MyService();
    MyType m = new MyType();
    m.x = 10;
    m.s = "That's it!!!";
    service.myObj = m;
    string s = service.SomeMethod();
```

This works smoothly. Now I need to change this to WCF. Found many topics about how to sign soap header with WCF, but all are about how to use MessageContract  as an attribute of a class which will be given to the operation as a parameter. Like this:

```
<code>
    [MessageContract]
    public class MyType
    {
       public int x;
       public string s;
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public string SomeMethod(MyType myType)
    {

    } </code>
```

But this is not what I need, my method must remain the same (with no parameter).

Few blogs talks about using WCFExtra lib or implement Client Dispatcher interface to add SOAP Header to every outgoing request. But again, I want migration of web service to WCF shouldn't affect my client, and they are not required to do any code changes, they should be able to consume the web service with .asmx extension. Also, the current web service uses MTOM and WSE-3. Is there any easy way.

Please help me with this.

I have already read following articles, but none of them talk about how to handle SOAP Header, WSE-3:

```
http://megakemp.com/2008/11/27/migrating-aspnet-web-services-to-wcf/
http://megakemp.com/2008/11/27/migrating-aspnet-web-services-to-wcf/
http://vikasbhardwaj15.blogspot.in/2012/05/convert-asmx-web-services-to-wcf.html
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/trobbins/archive/2006/12/02/integrating-wcf-with-your-existing-asmx-services.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2006/10/05/phased-migration-from-asmx-to-wcf.aspx
http://www.manas.com.ar/waj/2007/05/31/asmx-to-wcf-migration/
```

Answer (score 1):

In the past I would extract the WSDL from the asmx. Then I'll run it against [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) with argument `/mc`, which generates the service and message contracts. I'll then refactor the code to behave the same. For most part it works, but there are some gotchas.

From the code you posted, you want to encapsulate the "myObj" as a header in a request and response message, similar to the following:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyType
{
    [DataMember]
    public int x;

    [DataMember]
    public string s;
}

[MessageContract]
public class SomeMethodRequestMessage
{
    [MessageHeader] public MyType myObj;
}

[MessageContract]
public class SomeMethodResponseMessage
{
    [MessageHeader] public MyType myObj;
    [MessageBodyMember] public string result;
}

// Inside your service contract

[OperationContract]
public SomeMethodResponseMessage SomeMethod(SomeMethodRequestMessage message)
{
   // do stuff
}
```

See [Using Message Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx).

Comment: Werner, thanks for your reply. Yes I have already tried that as well, to generate the code using WSDL file passing to svcutil.exe But the problem is, it changes the Method Signature. I want the method signature to be Same. If my web method which uses SOAP Header, has a signature like  public void Add(String atr1, String str2), then it should remain same even after migrating from web service to WCF

Comment: The only way I know of to use strongly typed headers (aka MyType) is to pass it along as a message contract to the method body. Why don't you want to change the operation signature operation? Its two different implementations for the exact same SOAP message.

Comment: That is the problem, I cant change the Operation Contract signature. Changing the signature means, affecting all the clients who are using the web service.

Comment: That isn't always the case. The same physical soap request/response can be represented in many different ways in code. You do have to take some care though regarding namespaces and type names. It looks like you may be confusing message contracts with data contracts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I need the OperationContract (the Webmethod) signature to be same. Anyway I will try your proposed solution and will let you know.